# I've been bitten by a cave spider, how can I cure the poison?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been bitten by a cave spider in a dungeon and now I'm poisoned. I'm taking too much damage when poisoned and I want to be cured.

I know when eating rotten flesh, I can be poisoned too, so an antidote could also help those who have eaten it.

What's the remedy?

Comment: The poison effect from eating rotten flesh is different, and more similar to being "sick"; you don't loose any health, so it won't kill you, but it does make you hungry again faster. This "Hunger" effect is also cured by Milk.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of Beta 1.9, drinking [Milk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Milk) cures poison, as well as [other potion effects](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion_effects).

Answer (score 1):

You can drink milk, I've tried it a bunch of times and it works.

You get the milk by getting a bucket and right click on a cow. It might take a few tries to get milk but just keep right clicking.

I'm sure you may want to save milk for a cake, but would you want to lose your stuff to a death just because you want a cake instead of getting more milk after you respawn?

There is a bunch of poisons and stuff that could kill you, so I say always bring a couple buckets of milk.

Comment: There is no need to choose between making a cake or curing poison. Even if you use the milk to make a cake, you get the bucket back, and all you have to do is re-click the cow; they never run out of milk.